# Writing a grammar for matching parenthesis and brackets. Is this a correct answer?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

Write a grammar that generates strings that contain matched brackets and parentheses. Examples of valid strings are:

```
[([])]

()()[[]]

[[]][()]()
```

Examples of invalid strings are:

```
[}

[[]

()())

][()
```

My answer:

```
< string > -> < term >*

< term > -> (< string >) | [< string >]
```

If this works the way I think it does than a < string > turns into zero or more terms which are then put in brackets or parenthesis and then filled with zero or more terms again. However I'm not sure about the asterisk and haven't been able to find any examples of someone using it the way I did.

Sorry if I'm way off.

Comment: Typically, CFGs don't use stars (that's more of a regex construct), but your basic setup looks good!

Comment: I've seen CFG's that have *, +, ? in them. You can avoid it but it's more awkward.

Comment: It is more conventional to include no spaces in the non-terminal symbols such as `<string>` (at least, not between the `<` and the first character of the name, nor between the last character of the name and the `>`).  Use spaces to separate your terminals (`()[]`) from the non-terminals.  It is also more common to use `::=` than an arrow to separate the LHS from the RHS of a rule.  However, given that a `<string>` can be empty because of the `*`, the rule looks approximately correct.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the answer was:

< S > -> < S >< S > | (< S >) | [< S >] | () | []

mine was "not valid in BNF, no base cases", Oh well.

Comment: Isn't `S -> SS | (S) | [S] | ε` also valid? Given Jonathan's remark above, seems like you do have a base case when `<term>*` is `ε`.